# jQuery function not moving... can't find anything wrong with it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to take these moving clouds: http://vintageskytheme.tumblr.com/ (it's a theme I've already bought from themeforest, but its for tumblr)

I'm trying to put it on wordpress. here: http://pawprintsinmypancakes.com/

it used to be $() function and i see it giving errors in console every 30 milliseconds so i know the rest of the code IS working... but when i change it to jQuery()... console is just silent. I have no idea whats wrong

Comment: If I had to guess your `$` is being overwritten by some other JavaScript library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things:

1: Change the following code:

```
//Set the CSS of the header.
jQuery('#head_interior').css("background-position", current + " bottom");
jQuery('#head_exterior').css("background-position", current2 + " bottom");
```

to this:

```
//Set the CSS of the header.
jQuery('#head_interior').css("background-position", current + "px bottom");
jQuery('#head_exterior').css("background-position", current2 + "px bottom");
```

Note the "px" added before the "bottom". You need these when setting css styles, because css allows for px, em, pt, etc... If you don't tell it what unit to use, it'll happily ignore your values.

That will get your clouds moving.

2: Your $ object is getting overwritten. Not sure where. I would also suggest you wrap your code in a call to the jQuery object, like so:

```
jQuery(function(){
// your existing code here
});
```

That is the standard way of doing things with jQuery so you don't pollute the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [jQuery noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: +1 If memory serves, I believe prototype has caused me to use this before

Comment: so what is the error in my code? i suck at jquery so hard, i dont even know how to use this